# GCC 4.5: Why no compiler warning on no-effect statement?

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I am using gcc 4.5 to compile a Linux kernel module. I just noticed that I have some code that looks like this:

```
#define NODE_ID      "string_here"

int foot(int a) {
    /* snip */
    NODE_ID;
    NODE_ID;
    /* snip */
    return 0;
}
```

I have these two no-effect statements, and the compiler never generates a warning telling me about them. Why is this? I wonder if there's other statements like this floating in my project that I haven't found.

Comment: Do you use the -pedantic flag?

Comment: GCC 4.5.4 generates warnings with just `-Wall` here (not even pedantic or a standards mode).

Comment: @Gray I do not use -pedantic, no.

Comment: Ah, well, it looks like all you'd need to catch issues like this is the -Wall flag. I guess they don't warn you because the compiler just drops it anyway. Only affects readability. Don't quote me on that, just a theory.

Comment: Hmmm.... recompiling with -Wall doesn't do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

It does warn you, you just weren't listening -- as @Mat said in the comments, you need to enable the [`-Wall` option](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), and it will warn you:

```
$ gcc test.c -c -Wall
test.c: In function ‘foot’:
test.c:5:5: warning: statement with no effect
test.c:6:5: warning: statement with no effect
```

Or, you can just enable the `-Wunused-value` option for just this warning, but I highly recommend using `-Wall`, which includes this and many other useful warnings.  You can also enable `-Wextra` and `-pedantic` for even more, but these sometimes give false positives for code which is perfectly fine, adding extra noise to your build process.  So use them judiciously.

Comment: Can you think of a reason for -Wall to get stepped on by another build flag possibly? Why when I enable -Wall would it not work?

Comment: @unexpected62 If you have a `-Wno-unused-value` or a `-w` after the `-Wall`, that would silence the compiler.